# Add button click as an event to this jQuery script?

Tags: jquery, events, onkeyup

Im working from this demo:
http://kilianvalkhof.com/uploads/listfilter/

I want to add a button that empties the input text area when you click it. I can do this with jQuery's .val however the list doesn't filter. I think the code does the recalculation after a keyup event, so how can I add clicking a button as an event that listened for? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works when I add this to my click function:

```
$('input.filterinput').change();
```

Comment: You asked the very unclear question and answered this easy answer in less then 2 mins. Did you even try before posting the question?

Comment: Yes, for about 20 mins. Sometimes the solution to a problem comes as soon as you stop trying.